# SQL - pre-definition using the view statement and access of views

Tags: sql-server

The idea is to pre-define the Min and the Max Funktion using the "view"-statement and than combine those 2 view tables and to get one output.
First, the max and min salaries (Gehalt) of each department (Abteilung) are gathered. Than they are combined with the workerID (Mitarbeiternummer), the first and last name and a columm were the words Min and Max are shown to clarify what it is exactly, min or max salary.

here the complete code:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_min_abteilung;
CREATE VIEW view_min_abteilung as (
    SELECT mi.abteilung, "min" AS ['Min Max'], MIN(mi.gehalt) AS Gehalt
       FROM mitarbeiter mi
       GROUP BY mi.abteilung
);

drop view if exists view_max_abteilung;
CREATE VIEW view_max_abteilung as (
    SELECT ma.abteilung, "max" AS ['Min Max'], MAX(ma.gehalt) AS Gehalt
       from mitarbeiter ma
       group by ma.abteilung
);

SELECT m.Mitarbeiternummer, m.Vorname, m.Name, mi.Abteilung, mi.['Min Max'], mi.Gehalt
   FROM view_min_abteilung mi, mitarbeiter m
   WHERE mi.abteilung = m.Abteilung and mi.Gehalt = m.Gehalt

UNION ALL

SELECT m.Mitarbeiternummer, m.Vorname, m.Name, ma.abteilung, ma.['Min Max'], ma.Gehalt
    FROM view_max_abteilung ma, mitarbeiter m
    WHERE ma.abteilung = m.Abteilung and ma.Gehalt = m.Gehalt

ORDER BY abteilung, minmax
```

So now, in the select statement combined by the UNION-statement I have to access the name of the "Min Max" columm and that is where the problem occurs, because the space between Min and Max make 2 functions out of it.
I always get error messages.

I tried to use several ways without success:
mi.['Min Max']  and ma.['Min Max']
as well as 
mi.'Min Max'  and ma.'Min Max'
but no luck

Any ideas??

Sorry that I didn#t explain myself properly

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Hello,

if the columm name has spaces and is made up from function-names, like Min and Max (columm name "Min Max", the name can be defined in the select-statement using single or double quotation marks.
"Min Max"

If you want to access this columm later on, the use of accents `  

Then the name is correct recognized and not the functions themselves

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write [Min Max] instead of ['Min Max'].
By the way there is no need for two separate views. You can use Min and Max in just one view.

Comment: Hello CPMunich, same result, the name is seen as 2 fucntions and error messages

Comment: And how do I combine the 2 view statements? If I put the 2 statements 'min' as 'minmax' and 'max' as 'minmax' in the same select statement, I get an error mesaage regarding dublicate columm name